# Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type 'String' when trying to add a new key,value to a map

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a map like this:

```
map = {
   'container_1':0,
   'container_2':0,
   'container_3':0,
}
```

That's being created from an iterable like this:

```
map=Map.fromIterable(containerList, key: (e)=>e, value: (e)=>0);
```

But when I try to add this key and value, I get an error:

```
map['user']='User Name';
```

The error I get is:

```
Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type 'String'
```

How do I add a key value to a map that has a different value type than what's already in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the map variable is `Map<String, int>`, so you couldn't add a `String` value to it. If you can change map type to `Map<String, Object>` then you will be able to add `String` value to it. Like this:

```
  final map = <String, Object>{
   'container_1': 0,
   'container_2': 0,
   'container_3': 0,
  };
  
  map['user'] = 'User Name';
```

Comment: The original map is actually getting created fromIterable. like map=Map.fromIterable(containerList, key:(e)=> e, value: (e)=>0); . I should have clarified that.

Comment: You can create new map with all values from map, like that: `final newMap = <String, Object>{...map};` and then you can add values to it, instead of the original map. You couldn't add `String` values to map with type `<String, int>` any how. Another way to change you code like that: `final map = Map.fromIterable(containerList, key:(e) => e, value: (e) => 0 as Object);` also should work.

Comment: would you be able to type out the full code for that? I'm not clear on what goes inside the brackets. I really appreciate it!

Comment: oh sorry just saw your full comment, that second way seems to make sense. Thank you!

Comment: It's a full code. It's just copy map with different type of map values.

Comment: yeah ignore my original comment, I didn't see your full response. The second way worked perfectly. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to initialize the map to have The key as String and the value as dynamic
Because  the dynamic makes your variable type to be determined at the run type with any errors

```
final map = <String, dynamic>{
   'container_1': 0,
   'container_2': 0,
   'container_3': 0,
  };
  
  map['user'] = 'User Name';
```

Comment: I should have clarified, the original map is being created fromIterable. Like so: map=Map.fromIterable(containerList, key: (e)=>e, value: (e)=>0);